# Google Analytics data extracted through Integration tool does not match true Google Analytics values

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

Data for the same range extracted through Google API and Google Analytics do not match exactly they are out by roughly 2-3%. I am using a 3rd party integration tool and Revenue, page views and sessions are not matching. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Which is giving you a larger number of sessions, GA dashboard or the API?

My guess is that the tool is looking at dimensions that do not match exactly with what you are trying in the GA dashboard.  It's also possible there is a time-zone issue.

You could use another method for downloading the data, such as python, and then compare that against the GA dashboard.  In my experience, that will match up if all the parameters are exactly the same.  Then you would be back to the same question: what is the tool doing differently?